# FireFox Declaration Dropped Errors

Tags: html, css, flash, firefox

I suddenly noticed today after updating Firefox that one of my webpages that has some older CSS and Flash coding doesn't seem to be working to properly anymore. Other browsers still work fine. I believe it to be the CSS itself and not the Flash as that works.

In Firefox some errors seen in the console when inspecting the elements :

```
Error in parsing value for ‘background’.  Declaration dropped
```

```
Expected color but found ‘top’.  Error in parsing value for ‘background’.  Declaration dropped
```

```
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘alpha(’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped
```

I'm assuming that this is possibly due to some deprecated coding in FireFox that isn't being read anymore and I was able to change a couple of these in one of my two css files but some of these others I'm at a loss as to what to remove and what to change.

The webpage is listed below for reference. (It's only the main background page block that turns white for some reason, everything else works fine).

http://roleplayevolution.com/evo/

**UPDATED**

With further testing after validating everything again (thank you @MrLister and @AlexanderO'Mara) I tested it with a colleague and on another machine that had older versions of Firefox. It works on **46.01** and **47.0.2** but as soon as you update to **49.0.2** it breaks, so I'll be looking into direct changes with Firefox and what might be the issue there.

However if someone knows more that would be awesome and if one of you guys puts an actual answer in I'll accept it for the coding help.

Comment: Sounds like some parsing errors. The thing with `filter: alpha(` is in reference to the obsolete non-standard CSS `filter` property in IE which is not the same as the modern `filter` property. You will need to show us what code has these problems though.

Comment: Was just researching that and am editing my question with examples of code. Don't know why I forgot that.

Comment: Things like `color: 2F6054;` produce errors, yes. (Hex colors need a `#`.) But that one would always have produced an error; it's not like Firefox's parsing engine has changed that much with the update.

Comment: I had thought that it would have always produced an error before as well, however it was working before the recent updates to 49.0.1 and now 49.0.2. (That does not mean to say however that it wasn't returning an error even though the rest of the page seemed to be loading correctly and I just didn't notice it until the rest of it happened, so thank you i've made that change)

Comment: It would be nice if the error message included the value that could not be parsed: the line number isn't always accurate when dynamic stuff is loaded.